# How to limit an aspect to a bean specified with a name?

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have the following interface:

```
public interface Performance {
    public void perform();
}
```

Implemented by the following class:

```
@Component
public class Woodstock implements Performance {

    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("Woodstock.perform()");
    }
}
```

The aspect I want to apply is this one:

```
@Aspect
public class Audience {

    @Pointcut("execution(* concert.Performance.perform(..)) "
            + "&& bean('woodstock')"
            )
    public void performance() {}


    @Around("performance()")
    public void watchPerformance(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Taking seats");
            jp.proceed();
            System.out.println("CLAP CLAP CLAP!!!");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Demanding a refund");
        }
    }
}
```

The configuration file for the program is declaring the following beans:

```
@Bean
public Audience audience(){
    return new Audience();
}

@Bean
public Performance woodstock(){
    return new Woodstock();
}
```

And the test I'm running is this:

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("woodstock")
Performance performance;

@Test
public void test(){
    printBeanNames();
    performance.perform();
}
```

Now, in the Audience class I specified in the annotation that I want to apply the aspect for the perform() method from the interface concert.Performance (`execution(* concert.Performance.perform(..))`) and I am explicitly limiting the application of the aspect to the bean whose name is "woodstock" (`&& bean('woodstock')`).

But when I run it I see that the aspect is not applied to the woodstock bean, although that bean is the one being used (it prints `Woodstock.perform()`)

If instead of `bean()` I use `!bean()` then it does work, so it seems that it cannot consider that bean as the one named "woodstock".

Is there something wrong in the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special Spring AOP `bean()` pointcut works like `bean(myBean)` or `bean(*Bean)`, there are no inline single or double quotes around the bean name according to the [Spring AOP documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators) (scroll down a little bit in this chapter).